# Cut Google cardboard according to A4 size paper

Tags: google-cardboard

How to print Google cardboard to a4 size paper?
Can anyone provide A4 pdf file for google cardboard

I want to print Google cardboard on A4 paper and then cut the cardboard according to lines on A4 paper.

Help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need 3 pages to be printed. use print_yourself.pdf in  http://www.google.com/get/cardboard/downloads/cardboard_design_v1.0.zip

Answer (score -1):

I think  http://www.google.com/get/cardboard/downloads/cardboard_design_v1.0.zip not true for A4 size, it look small.

Comment: Its the official google template, if you need A4, postcard or any other size, you got to make your own.

Comment: What is the paper size this pdf to be printed on? letter size? or a5? or what?